# SSIS Connection Manager points to Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssis

I have created an SSIS package, and I have set the UserId and Password in Connection Manager. I have also pointed it to Log On to Server as SQL Authentication. Protection level is EncrypytSensitiveWithUserKey. However, when I executed the package, authentication seems to get the current user log on, and not the User Name that I have set earlier in Connection Manager.

However, when I tried to test the connection, it succeeds. But I notice that everytime I open the connection manager windows, log on to server is always set to Windows Authentication.

What could be the problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If its an existing package,  check if the connecton manager set with any expression?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is an expression, a variable named connectionString, username and password for the database are also set there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for expression evaluation property  .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms141214(v=sql.105).aspx

So ,its not overriding default connection.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, Ashish.